# Jquery Nested Promises inside ForEach loop

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to return a promise from nested promises that are inside of a loop?  I'm not sure how to use when or how to get out of nesting the promises.

```
function UploadDocuments()
{

_.forEach(documentArray, function (document) {

             uploadHelper.uploadFile(document.file, "Doclib").done(function (results) {

                //success
                uploadHelper.getDocumentListItem(results.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri).done(function (listItem) {

                    var payLoad = {
                        "Title": document.title,
                        "FileLeafRef": document.title,
                    };

                    //success
                    uploadHelper.updateDocumentListItem(listItem.d.__metadata, payLoad).done(function () {
                        alert("Successfully Uploaded Document");

                    }).fail(function () {

                        alert("Upload failed");
                    });

                }).fail(function () {

                    alert("get listItem failed");
                });

            }).fail(function () {

                alert("upload failed");
            });

        });

}
```

I want to be able to to call this function return a promise and then continue on with processing. afterwards such as

```
UploadDocuments().then(function(){
      //continue
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a great way, or at least I can't think of one, to do what you are doing in a loop. A promise can only resolve once, so it would have to be after the loop finished running, but assuming your uploadHelper object has mostly async methods, there is no guarantee those async operations would have passed/failed by time the loop ends and the promise resolves.

It seems like a better pattern might be the [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which takes an array of async operations wrapped in promises and resolves if all of them pass. It would take some reworking of you helper methods, but you could loop through the docs and add a promise that does all of you doc processing to an array, then call Promise.all() on the resulting array.

Comment: Yeah,I'm a little stumped, the uploadhelper returns .ajax promise, it is just calling to a rest api (SharePoint 2013). I'm uploading each file, then getting each document listitem, then updating each listitem. Not sure the best way to chain or handle errors if one part of the chain fails.

Comment: Yeah, that is the downside of Promise.all(). If one promise is rejected, then the whole thing gets rejected. Most of the utility of a promise is that you are sure operation after it have access to the return data, but it doesn't seem like you are returning anything from the last call? Is something not working, or are you just looking for a better pattern?

Comment: Just looking for a better pattern and would like to continue if one document fails upload but  I guess it would since I have the loop outside the calls